# how to change the colors of TProgressBar (background/progressbar itself) to a (custom) color in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

Original question was about TGauge, however as pointed out in the comments it's not recommended to use, plus any attempts to set the displayed (% text) caption to a custom color would break the inversion (as it's color is just inverted from the background) aka it would not be half colored anymore.

So I am going to use the TProgressBar, but there's still the issue of it's colors (background/progressbar itself) which doesn't seem to have an explicit property to change, it is tied with the current windows theme but there should be a way of ignoring that.

Comment: you can't do that directly with TGauge. you need to create an ancestor and override the Paint method.

Comment: @kobik I see. I know squat about Paint method and just scratched the surface of how to override stuff, I guess I'm off to search for the answers, but also maybe you could point me to some comprehensive resource for that?

Comment: The way the partial coloring works is directly related to inverting the colors; it's done using an `XOR` of the foreground color at the site the label is being painted. (See the source for `TGauge`.) If you remove the inversion by replacing the color, you'll remove the ability to partially color the text as well. I'd suggest, though, that you not use `TGauge` - it's a leftover Delphi 1 component, and looks really dated. Modern UIs use a progressbar and, if you want to display text progess as well, display a separate label above or to the right of the progressbar.

Comment: @Ken, I didnt see a way to change the colors of ProgressBar (background and the progress itself), except for State, but I'm not sure if that impacts the way the progressbar functions or something, as well as I also preferred the "simpler" look of the TGauge. If I can at least adjust the look and change colors I'd gladly switch to the progressbar.

Comment: Colors for `TProgressBar` are generated by Windows, and work with the theme support. So in actuality, by selecting the theme that's in use the user decides the colors of things. You can't really do it yourself. This is as designed when themes were introduced in Windows. I guess writing your own `TGauge` descendent is really your only option, unless you go to a third-party progress bar that supports selectable colors. (Did you check [torry](http://www.torry.net) to see if there's a free scrollbar that does what you want?)

Comment: @Ken, I'm trying to do stuff with default components available at first, there's a wide selection of gauges/progress bars there, I have not yet looked into any of them

Comment: I'm sorry I had a typo: I wrote "ancestor" should have been "descendant". TGauge is by far not a "default component". it is meant to be a demo component shipped with Delphi. so either find set of colors that looks nice for you or use another custom progress component.

Comment: Might sound silly, but if you don't know anything about the Paint method, why not just set the gauge to NOT show the %, slap a label on top and have it display the progress there instead? Just a thought!

Comment: @LaKraven, yes, that's what I will go for if no other alternative presents itself.

Comment: TGauge is a sample component, you can easily modify its source.

Comment: @Ken, I did find a nice looking component (minus the caption), however there's a slight glitch with it's first steps (1,2) on a scale of 100 (max) (1-34 on a scale of 1000) - position of the drawn progress bar in that particular range doesn't budge... I'd love if someone could look at the code and find what's causing it (www.torry.net/vcl/indicat/meters/TQProgressBar.zip), I dont think I can figure it out anytime this month...

Comment: Use TProgressBar (Win32 component): you can change its colours with a message.

Comment: @No'amNewman, can you elaborate on that whole message part as I'm sure I don't follow?

Comment: @KenWhite, dumb question, but where should the source for TGauge be? I dont seem to be able to find it in delphi's install dir and as far as I remember the install should have been full.

Comment: @Raith: The easiest way is to drop the component on a form, compile your project (to have the IDE update the uses clause), and then click on the `Gauges` unit and hit Ctrl+Enter (or right-click and choose `Open File At Cursor` from the context menu).

Comment: @KenWhite, just as I suspected it appears I dont have the Gauge.pas, frankly any unit from uses clause opens the \RAD Studio\Projects\ dir if I use Ctrl+Enter and Ctrl+LMB just gives me "Unable to locate file name.pas". Source files should be included, so what's going on... I don't suppose it could be because I didn't install delphi into the default directory?

Comment: @Raith: What version of Delphi are you using? Is it the personal version, or one of the Turbo Versions? They were the only ones ever released since Delphi 2 that didn't include source. (Delphi 1 didn't include it, but you could buy it as part of a "power pack" or something.)

Comment: @KenWhite, It's delphi 2010. How is everything even functioning if there's no source files, well there are dcu files, but I might be talking out of my ass, cause I dont know anything...

Comment: The dcus are all that are required to compile an application, as long as they're compiled with the same version of the compiler you're using to compile your own source. But as I said, almost all versions of Delphi have included source. It should be located in your (DelphiInstallFolder)\Source folder, in several subdirectories (VCL, RTL, Common, and so forth). Why not just search your hard disk (with Windows Explorer, for instance) for `Gauges.pas` (or `Gauges.*`) to see if it's found? If it is, you'll know where the source files are, and if it's not you'll know you don't have it.

Comment: @KenWhite, reinstalling fixed this, I've searched before asking the question obviously, that's when/why I paniced a little, thanks anyway

Comment: Would everyone please take some of the feedback and update your question/answer and delete the comments that are not relevant?  This is becoming an *extended discussion* and it more suited for chat.  Remember, the focus on content on the Stack Exchange network is intended to be on the posts *not the comments*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't solve the problem for TGauge, but for TProgressBar (and I am aware that there was a strenous argument about another Delphi question yesterday about someone not answering the exact question as posed by the OP, so feel free to ignore). As others have pointed out, TGauge is deprecated and not recommended for use anymore. Here's the code necessary in order to change both the bar and background colour of TProgressBar.

```
ProgressBar1.Brush.Color:= clRed; // Set Background colour
SendMessage (ProgressBar1.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, clBlue); // Set bar colour
```

Comment: Thank you, since this is the suggested way of doing things anyway I might as well edit the question and accept this answer.

Comment: Maybe I was too hasty with accepting the answer, but why exactly does it give me this? `E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'PBM_SETBARCOLOR'`

Comment: Did you include the unit `CommCtrl` (XE2) in your uses directive ?

Comment: Now I have, and it works (who knew that ComCtrls and CommCtrl existed). It's also worth noting that theme support should be disabled, I was wondering why didnt the color change. However with that disabled the precision (as well as appearance) of the progressbar is terrible. There's no way to remedy that right? Even a not tweaked TGauge seems to look prettier in comparison.

Comment: After some more poking, the background does get changed this way even with themes (my `BorderWidth` was 0, so I didn't see the background at all, however this is for the whole ProgressBar1 component background and not the progress bar background), but the Progress Bar color stays the default green (from the theme I assume). If you disable the themes for the app you can actually set `BarColor`/`BackgroundColor` (this is the type of background I'd like to have changed) in the Object Inspector, this is silly really...

Comment: PBM_SETBARCOLOR message: Remarks: When visual styles are enabled, this message has no effect. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx